# yii CGridView date range

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I would like to use date range at CGridView, I called this two field from_date and to_date and they are public at model , the code is working but the problem is from_date and to_date are not working perfectly, when I select from_date the result is correct but if I select to_date it is only taking the last value which is to_date, so could you please assist me

at Model

```
public $from_date;
public $to_date;
//at Search()
!empty($this->to_date ) ? $criteria->addCondition('date <= "' . $this->to_date. '" ') : "";
!empty($this->from_date ) ? $criteria->addCondition('date  >= "' . $this->from_date . '" ') :  "";
```

at View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'bank-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function()  { jQuery('#from_date').datepicker({'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd'}) , jQuery('#to_date').datepicker({'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd'})   }",
'filter' => $model,    
'ajaxUpdate' => true,
'columns' => array(
'account',
'name',
array(
    'name' => 'date',
    'filter' => $this->widget( 'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model'          => $model,
            'attribute'      => 'from_date',
            'options' => array('firstDay' => 6, 'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'),
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 100px;' , 'placeHolder'=>'From:' , 'id'=>'from_date'),
        ), true ) . $this->widget( 'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model'          => $model,
            'attribute'      => 'to_date',
            'options' => array('firstDay' => 6, 'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'),
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 100px;' , 'placeHolder'=>'To:', 'id'=>'to_date'),
        ), true ),
),
array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

please note I copied part of code so, if I forget some brackets or columns sorry

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your condition needs to make use of BETWEEN sql ...

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('attributeName', 'value1', 'value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set THIRD parameter in your addCondtion() like this way, without it only one condtions will be used.

```
$criteria->addCondition('t.id',$variable, 'AND'); // see
```

See More:http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail

EDIT:

```
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->addCondition('from_date',$this->from_date,'AND');
 $criteria->addCondition('to_date',$this->to_date,'AND');
```

Comment: Being Thanks for your time, I am using one column for date range, so if I use from_date and to_date there is an error because it does not match to database column, so I am using data column, I also added 'AND' Operator but no solution,

Comment: Why not use compare()?

Comment: because I need a range of date not equal date, I need to display date from 1 December 2014 to 14 January 2014, and I also tested compare